# Hibernate foreign key is null in OrderItem (order_orderID)

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have two table `Orders` and `OrderItem` as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer orderID;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date orderDate;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();

public Order() {
}

public Order(Date orDate, User currentUser) {
    this.orderDate = orDate;
    this.user = currentUser;
}

public Set<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
    return orderItems;
}

public void setOrderItems(Set<OrderItem> orderItems) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}

//getter/setters for orderDate, user
```

And

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Book book; // F.K to Book table
@Column(nullable = false)
private int quantity;
@Column(nullable = false)
private double totalPrice;

public OrderItem() {}
public OrderItem( Book currentBook, int qty, double totalPrice) {
    this.book = currentBook;
    this.quantity = qty;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}
//getter/setters
```

And here i initialize them to store in database:

```
@Transactional
public void storeOrderInDB() {

    order = new Order(currentDate(), currentUser); //date,user
    orderService.addOrder(order);

    OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
    orderItem.setBook(currentBook);
    orderItem.setQuantity(qty);
    orderItem.setTotalPrice(getTotalCost(qty, unitPrice));

    orderItemService.addOrderItem(orderItem);
}
```

This is the result:

`Orders`:

`OrderID: 5, OrderDate: "2015-04-25 23:11:16", userId: 1`

`OrderItem`:

`id:2 , quantity:1 , totalPrice:5000 , bookId:5 , order_orderID: null`

Why `order-orderID` is `null`?

I need it to be not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Order Entity` You have declared

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
```

Above declaration says that you foreign-key is maintain by Order Entity ,
 To resolve your problem

```
@Transactional
public void storeOrderInDB() {

Order order = new Order(currentDate(), currentUser); //date,user

OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
orderItem.setBook(currentBook);
orderItem.setQuantity(qty);
orderItem.setTotalPrice(getTotalCost(qty, unitPrice));
//orderItemService.addOrderItem(orderItem);
Set<OrderItem> orderItemSet=order.getOrderItems();
orderItemSet.add(orderItem);
order.setOrderItems(orderItemSet);
orderService.addOrder(order);
}
```

Hope this will resolve your problem
Thanks!

Comment: I got this compile time error: in `order.setOrderItems(order.getOrderItems.add(orderItem));`

Comment: `setOrderItems (java.util.set<OrderItem>) in Order cannot be applied to (boolean) `

Comment: Since `hashSet#add()` returns `boolean`.

Comment: Now the `order_orderID: null` still.

Comment: Should i save `both` sides or just `one` side?

Comment: Now, i save(`persist `) just `one` side (`order object`) , should i persist the `orderItem ` object too?

Comment: Or, should i declare  `@ManyToOne in OrderItem `POJO` for `Order` entity?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to define @ManyToOne.